# Error loading Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have been working on one project on my jupyter notebook for days but python stopped working for some reason. I continued working on file as I was editing some markdown cells.

After reopening jupyter, I am not able to open that file anymore:

[Getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QROa.png)

Other files are still opening. What are some options I can try to open this? Or is there any way I can open my ipynb file and copy the contents to another book?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this happens when our file has .~ prefix in the file directory. Removing that prefix and renaming the file works.